# Hide User Snap Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, usersnap

I have a button:

```
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.async = true;
  script.src ="my user snap api key";
  const firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
  script.id = "userSnap";
```

I want to hide it when a certain event is called:
I have tried this but it doesnt disappear
`document.getElementById('userSnap').remove()` 
the button is still there...
There is no css for it in it or anything so i cant adjust a css file it is just dont through user snap

Comment: This is confusing - what are you trying to do? You are not adding a button, you are adding a script... so what "button" are you trying to hide?

Answer (score 1):

The UserSnap script adds a button to the DOM. You can't hide the effects a script has had on the DOM by removing the script after it has run, instead you need to manipulate the DOM to hide or remove the button itself.

Use your browser's developer tools to figure out if the button has some kind of unique identifying attribute like an ID or class name, and use that to select and remove the button.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div id="userSnap">
    just testing
</div>
<a href="javascript://" onClick="remove_();">remove</a>
<script>
    function remove_(){
        document.getElementById('userSnap').remove();
    }
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48xqespg/)

Comment: If want to hide you can use `document.getElementById('userSnap').style.display='none';`